# How to set all \\ in arrays to be \\[1em]?

Tags: line-breaking, arrays

Everything is in the question. Right now, for instance, I must do this:

```
\begin{array}[t]{ccl}
\sin\theta & = & \sin\paren{\dfrac{2\theta}{2}} \\[1em]
& = & 2\sin\paren{\dfrac{\theta}{2}}\cos\paren{\dfrac{\theta}{2}} \\[1em]
& = & 2\dfrac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos^2\dfrac{\theta}{2} \\[1em]
& = & 2\tan\dfrac{\theta}{2}\times\dfrac{1}{1+\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}} \\[1em]
& = & \dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}
\end{array}
```

But I would like to be able to just use `\\` while still getting more spacing.

This particular behavior should only be applied in array environments.

Thank you.

Comment: do not use `array` for equations, it is desgined for arrays/matrices hence inline mode forcing you to use `\dfrac` as well as tighter line spacing. Use `align` or `aligned`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the thing is I want my equations to be just next to the text, which `array` with `[t]` does perfectly well

Comment: `aligned` with `[t]` can be used anywhere `array` with `[t]` can be used

Comment: awesome thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, you can use `\arraystretch` (macro) to increase the line spacing in an array.